# Does "Who knows" need a question mark?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, question-mark

Although "*who knows*" is almost as an expression for giving sense however, expressions can be statements, orders, and questions, so does the expression: "*who knows*" need a question mark?

Comment: Who knows if it needs a question mark... ;^)

Comment: There are a lot of related questions on this topic; try searching this site for "question mark".

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71193/punctuating-question-tags-a-question-mark-is-always-required-isnt-it-well#

Comment: @J.R. Certainly **not** an ellipsis!

Comment: Who knows – I sometimes put a dash.

Answer (score 10):

"Who knows?" is an example of a rhetorical question, because it is really a statement that does not actually ask for an answer.

The consensus is that it's sometimes OK to skip question marks for rhetorical question. Some people will say you shouldn't ever skip a question mark for a rhetorical question, and no one minds if you use a question mark, so I suggest that you do. (Personally, rhetorical questions without question marks always throw me off -- John Grisham has a habit of doing this and it causes me to read these sentences in a weird, sarcastic tone)

Here is more information from [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question#Grammar)

> Depending on the context, a rhetorical question may be punctuated by a
>   question mark (?), full stop (.), or exclamation mark (!),[6] but some
>   sources argue that it is best to use a question mark for any question,
>   rhetorical or not.[7]

Comment: How dare you say that?

Comment: How dare you say that!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you just invalidated my answer, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: To be fair, I was just spelling out KO's KO.

Comment: Clever, @EdwinAshworth!  But no I don't think this invalidates the answer.  It isn't really a rhetorical question with the exclamation mark; it becomes something else.  An _exclamation_, in fact.

Comment: @ Cyberherbalist: I'm with Wikipedia here: 'A rhetorical question is a figure of speech in the form of a question that is asked in order to make a point. ...The question is used as a rhetorical device, posed for the sake of encouraging its listener to consider a message or viewpoint. Though these are technically questions, they do not always require a question mark.' Embedded questions are not true questions either: An embedded question is a part of a sentence that would be a question if it were on its own, but is not a question in the context of the sentence:
I don't know where she has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to put a question mark for "Who knows?" simply because MacMillan Dictionary has done so in a similar example.

See for yourself:
who knows/cares/wants/needs etc SPOKEN
used for saying that you do not know/care etc, and you think that no one else does
'Won't Terry be upset?' 'Who cares? He never thinks about anyone but himself.'

Link: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/who#who-knows-cares-wants-needs-etc

Comment: "Simply because"?  I don't think any dictionary should be treated with such reverence.