# Correct punctuation when "I was wondering..." (or similar) is used to imply or restate a question?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, questions, syntactic-analysis

What is the correct punctuation when repeating a question as a statement?

See the following example, and my best guess:

> John: Sorry I missed your phone call. What's happening?
>
> Bob: I was wondering if you wanted to get some lunch.

My discomfort with Bob's response is the following: Bob's response *very strongly alludes to an underlying question*, but because it is technically a statement, it doesn't get punctuated with a question mark.

#### Question:

**If I wanted to communicate this response but include a question mark** (to more obviously visually communicate that there is a question that needs answering), **how could this be done?**

My best idea is to *simply restate the question in its entirety* and join with a colon. For example (please correct me if any part of is incorrect):

> I was wondering: "Do you want to get some lunch?"

Comment: All I'd do is add a comma: "I was wondering, do you want to get some lunch?" Now you separated setting the stage from asking a question.

Comment: Answered at [Is there a word or term to describe a statement that implies a question so sufficiently that the question is not actually included?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138488/is-there-a-word-or-term-to-describe-a-statement-that-implies-a-question-so-suffi) (The question mark **would** normally be added thus: << Bob: I was wondering if you wanted to get some lunch? >> ) (if one wishes to prompt for an answer; in speech, rising intonation is the marker).

Comment: Thank you, @EdwinAshworth, I tried to find related questions before asking, but didn't know how others might describe this same concept.

Comment: No problem. I wish there were two set comments: 'Answered at X, but it's no wonder you couldn't find this' (as in this case) and 'Answered at X, as you would have found if you'd bothered to look'. // Your rewrite with the colon is quite acceptable (perhaps a little ungainly). The colon is not so much in favour nowadays, but punctuation around quotes and 'near-quotes' is not so prescriptively regulated. I'd use a dash instead: << I was wondering – do you want to get some lunch? >> Except in the most formal writing, nobody but a hyper-prescriptivist of a certain era would seriously object.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321404/should-questions-phrased-as-declarations-end-with-a-question-mark/325511#325511