# A question about question marks

Tags: punctuation

I consider the second sentence more a statement than a question and have used a period. Is the following  correct?

> Is she drawn back into the past for a reason? Or is it all simply a horrible accident.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use a question mark for the second.  But their use is highly subjective, and often depends on the "tone" and inflection you wish to convey.

Comment: Thank you Hot Licks. So if I intend the second sentence to be more a statement ... using a period if I want to make the tone or voice drop when reading it would be okay grammatically?

Comment: It depends on whether this text is being graded by a punctuation P-ist or not.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71193/punctuating-question-tags-a-question-mark-is-always-required-isnt-it-well).

Comment: Agreed, Robusto.

Comment: It definitely calls for a question mark in my view. That is not to say that there aren't instances of doubt as to whether one should be applied; e.g. *She wondered who it could possibly be*. I am of the view that it is a statement, but I have seen question marks after such as that. Obviously *'Who could it possibly be?', she wondered* is another matter.

Answer (score 5):

The second sentence contains the inversion "is it" that signals a question.

If you want to use a period, I suggest you remove the inversion to make it a conjecture:

- Maybe it is all simply a horrible accident.

Comment: That's good advice Brian. I like your suggestion.