# Correct comma usage with "but after years of"

Tags: commas

I'm wondering if the comma usage is correct in the following sentence ("Brachyura" and "the Twelve" are proper nouns)?

- "The priestesses of Brachyura may hold the answers she seeks, but after years of protecting the secrets of the Twelve can they still be trusted?"

Should there not be an additional comma after the "but", or a comma after the word "Twelve", or are these optional?

Many thanks

Comment: The comma after 'but' is optional but would not be favoured in these days of avoidance of comma clutter. There really needs to be _some_ punctuation, if only to aid parsing / breathing, after 'seeks', at least a comma, though a more dramatic pause can be signalled by choosing a dash (or ellipsis). A comma after 'Twelve' is acceptable, but (especially if one isn't used after 'but') not preferable. The smooth-flowing (no punctuation after 'seeks,') version is fine and the one I'd choose. As you apparently have done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma after a coordinating conjunction preceding a parenthetical at the start of the sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246748/comma-after-a-coordinating-conjunction-preceding-a-parenthetical-at-the-start-of) (Here, I'm recommending that the parenthetical _after years of protecting the secrets of the Twelve_ is best 'offset' by zero punctuation rather than commas etc).

Comment: Excellent Edwin, thank you for your clear and precise answer, the question can be closed!